# output in text file is not the same as python output

Tags: python

I came across a problem. Whenever I run the code the output in Python is correct. all numbers show like this.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

When writing the output to a file. all the numbers are stored in a single line like this:

```
12345
```

anybody able to help out?

this is the code:

```
def main():
    Numberfile = open ('number_list.txt', 'w')
    s = 0
    while s < 100:
        s += 1
        Numberfile.write(str(s))
        print (s)
    Numberfile.close()  


main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print()` adds *newlines* for you. Writing to a file does not.

Either add the newline explitily:

```
Numberfile.write(str(s) + '\n')
```

or use the `print()` function for writing to the file:

```
print(s, file=Numberfile)
```

This all assumes you are using Python 3; in Python 2, you can still replace the `print` statement with the same `print()` function on a module-by-module basis by adding:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of the module.

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` on Python 2

Comment: Yup, I went out on a limb and assumed that the OP is using Python 3.